# Toggling Mouse Lock

Tags: c#, unity

I've been having some trouble toggling on and off the `Cursor.lockMode` and `Cursor.visible`. My goal is that when you are playing, the cursor is locked and invisible, and when you press escape, a pause menu pops up (already done that) and the mouse is visible and moveable again. I have tried using an `if` statement in the Update void, but that only ran for one frame. Does anyone have any answers? I'm a little new to c# so cut me some slack.

Code (c#):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CursorHideShow : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Cancel")) {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Cancel")) {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**First things first:**
Your `Update()` method is never unlocking the cursor or making it visible since you are immediately locking and setting it invisible afterward in the same frame, using the same conditional (`if` check). Why it works for even one frame, I don't know.

To toggle the cursor state, you need something like this..

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel")) {
        Cursor.visible = !Cursor.visible; // toggle visibility
        if (Cursor.visible) { // if visible, unlock
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        } else {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
    }
}
```

**Two:**
Can't confirm myself, but this may be a bug in Unity5.
[Unity Forum - Cursor Lockstate Troubles](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cursor-lockstate-troubles.278221/)